# A question about ffmpeg drawtext, After 60 seconds, display 5 seconds interval 5 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add a watermark to my video, but I don't want to add it at the beginning of the video,  After the beginning of video ,about 60s, I want the watermark to display every 60s for 30s. How should i write：

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=MS.ttf:text='TEST':x=w-500:y=h-150:start_number=250:enable=lt(mod(t\,60)\,30):fontsize=40:fontcolor=white:shadowy=2" -c:v h264_videotoolbox -b:v 2000k -s 1280x720 output.mp4
```

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After the beginning of video ,about 60s, I want the watermark to display every 60s for 30s*

Change `enable` to

```
enable=gte(t\,60)*lt(mod(t\,60)\,30)
```